# Is it possible to clear the Spring gem's cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring-gem

I'm trying to complete an assignment that creates a near identical application to a previous assignment. It calls for an application called `todolists`. This is the same as the previous assignment so, in order to be able to start fresh I renamed the previous assignment to `todolists_mod1`. I then discovered the issue is with the `Spring` gem keeping a record of the previous assignment.

I know I can disable `Spring` using the `DISABLE_SPRING` variable. This seems a bit tedious to me.

Is there a way I can force `Spring` to drop the previous assignment's application from its cache or otherwise clear the cache entirely without uninstalling the gem?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue that you are having, but it is a tad similar. I had an issue where for some reason `rails s` and `rails c` were using two different database settings.

I had been using one database.yml config for a while and then altered it recently. When I ran `rails s` it used the new database config, but when I ran `rails c` it used the old config for some reason.

After trying a few different things to no avail I stopped Spring(`spring stop`) and then re-ran `rails c` which auto-started Spring. After that `rails c` started using the new configuration.

Again I have no idea if this is the answer you are looking for, but it did help me.

--EDIT--

To be clear, when I stopped Spring I ran `spring stop` inside of the top level of my application directory.